# For each loop not looping through everything

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, for-loop

I have a loop that runs in an onEnter function (bad i know). I only want it to run once but it doesnt loop through every object. I think it doesnt have time before the next frame runs. Any ideas on how to make it loop all the way?

```
private function onEnter(e: Event) {

        if (deleteThis == true) {
            if (timer == 0 || 1) {
                if (checkExplosion == false) {
                    gotoAndStop(2)
                    if (Main.bloonList.length > 0) {
                        for each(Main.bloon in Main.bloonList) {
                            if (Main.areaOfCollision(Main.bloon, this, 0)) {


                                if (Main.bloon.currentFrame != 5) {
                                    Main.money++;
                                    Main.bloon.nextFrame();
                                    Main.bloon.gotShot();
                                } else {
                                    Main.money++;
                                    Main.bloon.deleteBloon();
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    checkExplosion=true
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Edit - deleteBloon();

```
public function deleteBloon()
    {
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `for each(var bloon in Main.bloonList)`

Comment: I think you missed my point. The edit you suggested didn't work. I meant that the cannon fires and hits a few bloons, it checks every bloon if it got hit by the explosion. Some bloons get destroyed but others don't. Do you understand me a bit more now?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, each instance of `Main.bloon` is in the `Main.bloonList` array?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me... do you have multiple instances with the same name (which you shouldn't have)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this:

```
if (timer == 0 || 1)
```

Should be this:

```
if (timer == 0 || timer == 1)
```

Then you may need to change the code a little bit. Something like this could work. I do suspect your issue may actually lie in the deleteBloon function, though. Without seeing it I can't be sure, but there is nothing (technically) wrong with your for loop.

```
private function onEnter(e: Event) {
    if (deleteThis == true) {
        if (timer == 0 || timer == 1) {
            if (checkExplosion == false) {

                gotoAndStop(2);

                if (Main.bloonList.length > 0) {
                    // This isn't optimised as I wasn't sure what Main.bloon could be
                    for each(var bloon:Main.bloon in Main.bloonList) {

                        if (Main.areaOfCollision(bloon, this, 0)) {

                            if (bloon.parent && bloon.currentFrame != 5) {
                                bloon.nextFrame();
                                bloon.gotShot();
                            } /*else {
                               // Make sure that deleteBloon is deleteing the correct array index. This is likely where the issue is. 
                                bloon.deleteBloon();
                            }*/

                            Main.money++;

                        }

                    }

                }

                checkExplosion = true;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

This would be in bloon:

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

function gotShot():void{
    // second parameter is time in milliseconds before executing
    setTimeout(deleteBloon, 250);
}
```

Comment: Same result, as i said im pretty sure it has something to do with next frame firing before the end of the loop

Comment: The loop will complete regardless, as you're running through all of the instances of bloons within your bloonList. Do you mean that it -is- firing the nextFrame correctly, but is then not deleting the bloon on certain ones?

Comment: The bomb is exploding but is only deleting half of the bloons it hits, random ones not any specific ones like first or last.

Comment: That's probably because your areaOfCollision is no longer true for that bloon. You should remove the bloon.deleteBloon() and change it to be called within the gotShot function. I'll update with an example.

Comment: I've updated. Note that I've also commented out the deleteBloon call from the inital loop. You'll need to update your code within gotShot() to include the new code that I've added. A good alternative would probably be a tween, with an onComplete function call to deleteBloon (http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) -> TweenMax.to(this, 1, {alpha: 0, onComplete: deleteBloon});

Comment: I dont even know anymore, i get your logic but    TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Bloon/deleteBloon()[C:\Users\liam\Dropbox\Everything\Bloons\Code\Bloon.as:32]
 at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()

Comment: this.parent.removeChild(this); which is fixed by if(stage)
    {
    this.parent.removeChild(this);
   } but now its deleting every bloon, can i send you full source and swf?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57064/discussion-between-kevin-mcgowan-and-bennettliam).

Comment: setTimeOut is deprecated, don't show code examples with deprecated feature. Use Timer instead. Voted down.

Comment: @BotMaster `setTimeOut` is depreciated? Doubtful... You'll need to show some proof before I'll believe you. (Though I will agree that using Timers is better).   Using `setTimeout` does not make the answer not useful.

Comment: setTimeOut is an AS2 legacy. Code example showing that, useful or not, should be voted down imo. They only teach beginners to use crappy short cuts that will make they code more difficult to debug and maintain.

Comment: @BotMaster Where is your proof? You may feel it's legacy, but that doesn't make it so from Adobe or Apache's perspective.  Show me something official that says it's depreciated and only around for legacy support...